# javac compiler error for a source file that is not provided

Tags: java, jaybird

I'm getting this error when I run `javac -d classes myfiles...`.  The strange thing is, I do not have PooledPreparedStatementHandler.java in any folder nor do I have the PooledPreparedStatementHandler sub-string in any of my source files.  The only reference I found was PooledPreparedStatementHandler.class in the jaybird jar (used and needed in my classpath).

```
./lib/jaybird-full-2.1.6.jar (all class files, no java files)
```

Here is the error:

```
org/firebirdsql/pool/PooledPreparedStatementHandler.java(org/firebirdsql/pool:PooledPreparedStatementHandler.java):32: package org.apache.xalan.lib.sql does not exist
import org.apache.xalan.lib.sql.XConnection;
```

This is the compile command:

```
find src/main/java -type f -name "*.java"| xargs javac -target 1.5 -d war/WEB-INF/classes
```

What is the source of this error?  I'm using oracle javac 1.6.0_26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [source code](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/firebirdsql/jdbc/jaybird/2.1.6/jaybird-2.1.6-sources.jar!/org/firebirdsql/pool/PooledPreparedStatementHandler.java?format=ok), it looks like `PooledPreparedStatementHandler` tries to import `org.apache.xalan.lib.sql.XConnection`, so you're dependent on it. And as you don't have that on your build classpath, you're getting the error.

Comment: I think your describing a run-time dependency.  The code, with jaybird classes jar, compiles in eclipse.  Eclipse 'Open Type' does not show any XConnection class by Apache.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the actual Jaybird 2.1.6 source does not reference this class: http://firebird.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/firebird/client-java/tags/Jaybird_2_1_6/src/pool/org/firebirdsql/pool/PooledPreparedStatementHandler.java?revision=57506&view=markup

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a modified copy of the Jaybird sources inside your project that is compiled together with the rest of your code. The original Jaybird 2.1.6 version of [`org.firebirdsql.pool.PooledPreparedStatementHandler`](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/jaybird/blob/Jaybird_2_1_6/src/pool/org/firebirdsql/pool/PooledPreparedStatementHandler.java) (links to the 2.1.6 tag on GitHub) does not reference `org.apache.xalan.lib.sql.XConnection`.

It actually looks like it is trying to compile a version of `PooledPreparedStatementHandler.java`, and not just use the class from the Jaybird jar file. You might want to check if the result of `find src/main/java -type f -name "*.java"` includes any Jaybird `.java` files (ie in the org.firebirdsql.* packages).

You could also try to include [Xalan-J](https://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/) on your classpath while building. If a copy of `PooledPreparedStatementHandler` gets included in the destination folder, then the source file is somehow getting included in your build.

Comment: I see your point, so I grabbed Jaybird-2.1.6JDK_1.5.zip from Sourceforge and used the jaybird-full-2.1.6.jar within.  The check sums were different.  Same problem!  I may have gotten the jar from a maven repository and, who knows, a build process could have changed some bits.  Your both on to something, it is referencing a line in the code that does not exist.

Comment: It actually looks like it is trying to **compile** a version of `PooledPreparedStatementHandler.java`, and not just use the class from the Jaybird jar file. You might want to check the result of `find src/main/java -type f -name "*.java"` if it does not include any Jaybird `.java` files (ie in the `org.firebirdsql.*` packages).

Comment: yes, i did check the results... all my own code.  also, that is why I did the egrep inside of source files to try and find some embedded classes.

Comment: You could try to include [Xalan-J](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/) on your classpath while building. If a copy of `PooledPreparedStatementHandler` gets included in the destination folder, then the source file is somehow getting included in your build.

Answer (score 0):

Mark actually gave me the answer in a comment.  If you want the points Mark, move it to a answer.  Until then, JayBird lists Xalan 2.3.1 as a [dependence](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.firebirdsql.jdbc/jaybird/2.1.6).  I just needed to include that in the classpath.